# I want to create an invisible clickable object over an image in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, click, mouse

So I'm creating a game in Java in which the user clicks on an image that's different from the rest. I've already got the images for the level created, but I just want to make it so that if the user clicks on a specific spot on the image, the game will react in moving on to the next image. (All of the images are placed in an array already.) The game is set up so that it opens with the first image already. Here's my code:

```
    package Final;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.*; 

    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class drawPictures extends JFrame implements MouseListener { //it implements this     because I want the user to click stuff
    //Now I need to declare the images that serve as my levels variables ahead of time.
    protected static Image levelOne;
    protected static Image levelTwo;
    protected static Image levelThree;
    protected static Image levelFour;
    protected static Image levelFive;
    protected Graphics g = this.getGraphics();  

    //Done declaring.

    //Now to load the images
    private static Image loadImage(String imgFileName) { 
        Image img = null;
        try {
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            img = tk.getImage(imgFileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Image not found: "+ imgFileName);
        }

        return img;
    } //done loading the images



    static Image [] pictureArray = new Image[5]; { //This is the array that will store all of     the images
     //otherwise known as the "levels"
    pictureArray[0] = levelOne; //each "slot" in the array is taken up by one 
    //of the images that serves as the level
    pictureArray[1] = levelTwo;
    pictureArray[2] = levelThree;
    pictureArray[3] = levelFour;
    pictureArray[4] = levelFive;
    }

    /*
     * Now that the actual array that stores the levels has been created
     * I need to create a method that "paints" the level, 
     * and moves on to the next one when the user clicks on something.
     * 
     * I also need to create a box with dimensions 151x159 
     * overtop of the happy tomato in the first level.
     * That will be the 
     */

    public drawPictures() {
     super("One of These Things Doesn't Belong...");


     setSize(1500, 750);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Creates the "x" box.
     setVisible(true); // Makes the window visible.    

     start();
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawImage(pictureArray[0], 100, 100, this);
 }

 public static void start() 
 /*
  * this entire method exists for the sole purpose of loading the images
  * that I placed in the variables that I declared above.
  * WHY IS PROGRAMMING SO DARN TEDIOUS???
  */
    {
    levelOne = loadImage("Level 1.jpg");
    levelTwo = loadImage("Level 2.jpg");
    levelThree = loadImage("Level 3.jpg");
    levelFour = loadImage("Level 4.jpg");
    levelFive = loadImage("Level 5.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        start();
        new drawPictures(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know where your image is drawn, you can easily determine the bounding rectangle of it.  Then, you can check if that rectangle contains a MouseEvent's `#getPoint()`.  Also, you've forgotten to actually add your MouseListener to any component (`#addMouseListener`).  As a final note, you should do your custom painting on a subclass of JPanel rather than the JFrame itself, and then add the mouse listener to that JPanel.

Comment: `protected Graphics g = this.getGraphics();` is incredibly bad!  Aprat from the fact that's possible for the method to return null, you should NEVER maintain a reference to any component's graphic context out side of the `paintXxx` methods

Answer (score 1):

You never add a mouse listener to the frame.

Having said that...

- You should avoid extending from top level containers, such as `JFrame`
- You should avoid painting onto top level containers (by overriding any of the `paint` methods)
- You should ALWAYS call `super.paintXxx` (unless you have an incredibly good reason to do otherwise) as the paint methods a rather complex and perform a lot of very import work
- Unless you're loading large images or downloading images from the Internet (even then), you should use the `ImageIO`.  It has support for a larger number of images.

In your mouse clicked event, you need to determine the current image that is begin displayed.  You need to determine is boundaries and determine if the mouse was clicked in it.

```
// Current index maintains the index of the current image...
// You should replace g.drawImage(pictureArray[0], 100, 100, this) with
// g.drawImage(pictureArray[currentIndex], 100, 100, this)
Image currentImage = pictureArray[currentIndex];
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, currentImage.getWidth(this), currentImage.getHeight(this));
if (bounds.contains(arg0.getPoint()) {
  // Image was clicked...
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= pictureArray.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
  }
  repaint();
}
```

**UPDATED with example**

This is a crude example.  Basically it uses a custom `JPanel` that paints the image.  To this I add a `MouseListener`.

The main program uses a folder and scrolls through, displaying each (valid) image on the image panel as you click.

Mouse clicks will only occur within the context of the image panel itself.

```
public class ImageScoller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ImageScoller();
    }

    public ImageScoller() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImageViewPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageViewPane extends JPanel {

        private ImagePane imagePane;
        private File[] fileList;
        private int currentIndex = -1;

        public ImageViewPane() {

            fileList = new File("/path/to/some/folder/with/images").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.isFile();
                }
            });

            imagePane = new ImagePane();
            imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    nextImage();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(imagePane);

            nextImage();
        }

        public void nextImage() {
            if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
                currentIndex++;
                if (currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                Image image = null;
                /*
                    Because I don't know the contents of the folder, this is a little
                    more complicated then it really needs to be.

                    If you know the file is an image, you can simply use ImageIO.read(file)
                */
                while (image == null && currentIndex < fileList.length) {
                    System.out.println("Loading next image: " + currentIndex);
                    try {
                        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fileList[currentIndex]);
                        if (iis != null) {
                            Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
                            if (imageReaders != null && imageReaders.hasNext()) {
                                ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();
                                imageReader.setInput(iis);
                                image = imageReader.read(0);
                            } else {
                                currentIndex++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            currentIndex++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        currentIndex++;
                    }
                }
                imagePane.setImage(image);
                invalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private Image image;
        private JLabel label;

        public ImagePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("No image available");
            add(label);
        }

        public void setImage(Image value) {
            if (image != value) {
                image = value;
                label.setVisible(image == null);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                int width = getWidth();
                int height = getHeight();
                int x = (width - image.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (height - image.getHeight(this)) / 2;
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want an invisible object above your image?

Anyway, to answer your question, create a JPanel located just as your image.

`JPanel yourPanel = new JPanel()` Set it's location same as your image.
Create a MouseListener on your JPanel.

```
yourpPanel.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mousePressed( MouseEvent evnt ){
      // Your code when clicked here
   }
});</code>
```

Comment: Why not just create a custom `JPanel` that is actually capable of painting the image and save the trouble of trying to layout two elements?

Comment: Because his question was, "How to create an invisible clickable object over an image". Before I typed my answer, I asked him "Why do you want an invisible object above your image?"

Comment: Uh oh, an argument. Okay, this would be my last comment :P. My answer was meant to answer his question not to criticize :D. It might not be the best approach, but it could be the 'closest' answer to something invisible on top of his image'.

Comment: Sorry, not meant to be an argument, I apologize if that's how it came across. I simply like to encourage answers that not only answer a question, but also encourage good practices, that's all ;)

Comment: Err... I broke my 'this would be my last comment' statement. Well, same here. Sorry for that. ;)